# Pagination a list of items inside a DetailView (many to many) Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, detailview

i have a model with a many-to-many relationship, i want print all items in that relationship from detailView with pagination (like 10 items for page) there is a way to get pagination automatic like in ListView?

```
class CardDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Card

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['banner'] = context['card'].banners.last()
        context['banner_slideshow'] = context['card'].banners.all().order_by('-created_on') #i need that list paginated
    
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Card.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query parameter and then put the page query in the context

```
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(query_set_for_m2m, ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except Exception as e:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    context['m2m_list'] = items
```

Put this code on your `get_context_data`, you can get the request from `self.request` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

Comment: It is not clear where to put this code.

Comment: @Soren elaborated